# How to separately collapse dynamic accordions inside a vue js v-for?

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I need to separately collapse accordions created inside a vue js v-for. I know that something like Id which can be used to separately identify the accordion will solve this. But don't know where to give this dynamic id?

Here is my HTML

```
<div role="tablist">
<div v-for="item in productFormData" v-bind:key="item.id">
  <b-card no-body class="mb-1">
    <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
       <b-button block v-b-toggle.accordion-productdetails variant="info">Product Details</b-button>       
    </b-card-header>

    <b-collapse
      id="accordion-productdetails"
      visible
      accordion="productdetails-accordion"
      role="tabpanel"
    >

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Name</span>
            <div>
              <span id="spnCustomerName">{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>


          </div>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a dynamic id to it you need to add index to the for loop so every time you use the index to identify the specific accordion like this, or you can use your item.id but i don't know the content of it:

CODEPEN :
https://codepen.io/emkeythekeyem/pen/WNbqeyM?editors=1010

```
<div role="tablist">
<div v-for="(item,index) in productFormData" v-bind:key="item.id">
  <b-card no-body class="mb-1">
    <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
       <b-button block v-b-toggle="'accordion-productdetails'+index" variant="info">Product Details</b-button>       
    </b-card-header>

    <b-collapse
      :id="'accordion-productdetails'+index"
      visible
      :accordion="'productdetails-accordion'+index"
      role="tabpanel"
    >

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Name</span>
            <div>
              <span id="spnCustomerName">{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>


          </div>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

see https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/collapse/#usage:

```
<!-- Using value -->
  <b-button v-b-toggle="'collapse-2'" class="m-1">Toggle Collapse</b-button>
```

EDIT :

Reviewing my code i noticed that the **accordion** param in `<b-collapse` needs to change also, just edit it to :

```
:accordion="'productdetails-accordion'+index"
```

I also edited the code of my first answer

Comment: I have tried that added index but it is still not working

<div v-for="(item,index) in productFormData" v-bind:key="item.id">
          <b-button block v-b-toggle="'accordion-productdetails'+index" variant="info">Product Details</b-button>
        </b-card-header>

        <b-collapse
          id="'accordion-productdetails'+index"

Comment: Am i missing some thing here?

Comment: Applying my code, is this what you want to accomplish ? 
https://codepen.io/emkeythekeyem/pen/WNbqeyM?editors=1010
Now the 3 accordions are separated trough a custom id, each has his own toggle  and they won't all toggle collapse if you click on just one.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, what you have done in the cidepen is exactly I needed. In my case even though I have given item.id I actually don't have an id inside productForm data. Will there be any relationship between item.id and the index?

Comment: If you don't have item.id you can simply use v-bind:key="index" as i'm seeing that in your initial code you are using it only for that purpose. There is no relationship.

Comment: Thanks Adrian  I will do the modifications and will let you know the updates later.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using Bootstrap 5 with [CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/), first import the `<link>` and JS `bundle` in the `public/index.html`.
2. The code is from the Bootstrap 5 [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/). Notice that the `flush-headingOne` has been changed to `'flush-heading'+index`.
3. Notice the `accordionCollection` could be imported from the js file with `data()`, or passed down from the parent props. The property `title`, `description` could be different defined in the array data.

HTML (template)

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accoridon-item" v-for="(accordionItem,index) in accordionCollection" :key="index">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" :id="'flush-heading'+index">
        <button
          class="accordion-button collapsed"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            :data-bs-target="'#flush-collapse'+index"
            aria-expanded="false"
            :aria-controls="'flush-collapse-'+index">
          {{ accordionItem.title }}
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div
        :id="'flush-collapse'+index"
        class="accordion-collapse collapse"
        :aria-labelledby="'flush-heading'+index"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
        <div class="accordion-body"> {{ accordionItem.description }} </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```